# ui-grid column definiton error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

When I load data to Ui-grid, I have this error `colDef.name or colDef.field property is required`

I didn't find on the internet a solution to solve this.

This is my function to fill the grid :

```
 $scope.ApiGet = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: //an url,
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',            
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            var token = data.access_token;
            console.log(token);
            $.ajax({
                url: //an other url
                async: false,
                crossDomain: true,
                type: "GET",
                datatype: "json",                    
                success: function (datas, textStatus, request) {
                    console.log(datas[0].previewContent);                        
                    angular.forEach(datas, function (value) {
                        console.log(value);
                        debugger;
                        if (value) {
                            $scope.rowCollection = $scope.rowCollection.concat(value.previewContent);
                        }

                    })
                   // console.log($scope.rowCollection);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    // $scope.addAlert(jqXHR.responseText != "" ? jqXHR.responseText : jqXHR.statusText);
                }
            })
```

And the Html

```
<div ng-controller="listCtrl" ng-init="ApiGet()"> 
    <div ui-grid="{ data: rowCollection }" class="myGrid"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are using jquery AJAX to send http requests, angular digest cycle might be stopped. so even though you assign `$scope.rowCollection` values, it will not bind to the html.

one thing you can do is start the digest cycle using `$scope.$apply()` after the http response

```
 success: function(datas, textStatus, request) {
     console.log(datas[0].previewContent);
     angular.forEach(datas, function(value) {
         console.log(value);
         debugger;
         if (value) {
             $scope.rowCollection = $scope.rowCollection.concat(value.previewContent);
         }

     })
     $scope.$apply();
 },
```

OR

you can use `$http` instead of `$.ajax` to send http requests

Comment: my request were async = false, so when I added $scope.$apply() it says me $Digest already in progress, so I put requests to async=true, then I have the same error. I tried to create gridOption with colum definition, still the same eroor

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution :

define a

```
$scope.gridOptions {data:mydata, 
                    columnDefs:[{field:'field1',displayName:'Field1", width:"*"},
                                {field:'field2',displayName:'Field2", width:"*"}]
```

Then in Html :

```
 <div ng-controller="listCtrl" ng-init="ApiGet()"> 
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="myGrid"></div>
 </div>
```